# how to configure `aptd` to really stop accessing the internet when the machine starts?

Tags: aptdaemon

I have already configured the software updates to NEVER check as recommended in other answers.

I don't want to uninstall any packages because I still I want to be able to check and update but ONLY WHEN I CAN.

I have a limited plan 100MB/day and if I am not fast, `/usr/bin/python3/usr/sbin/aptd` will start doing it's things and prevent me from doing other stuff the rest of the day...

I just need to PROPERLY disable the auto check for updates as apparently the graphical frontend wont let me do it :(

Well... that if... aptd is actually checking for updates at all.

Related: [Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 autoupdates regardless of settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816175/ubuntu-gnome-16-04-autoupdates-regardless-of-settings)

Obs.: I  tracked the PID using `nethogs`, went to /proc/PID and found it by the cmdline "file". The PID is dead by now, took about 10 to 20minutes I guess.

@N0rbert No, it is not a duplicate at [Do I really need apt-daily.service and apt-daily-upgrade.service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038923/do-i-really-need-apt-daily-service-and-apt-daily-upgrade-service). He asks "Do I really need apt-daily.service and apt-daily-upgrade.service?", nobody answered that, nobody answers if he actually needs that or not... The answers there are workarounds to overcome the slow startup.
Here, I still want to be able to reactivate that service anytime, I dont want to uninstall it, I think it is important, I could even answer there "yes dude, it is important, you need it, not that often of course, but that is useful to keep your OS secure", and that should be an acceptable answer there...
There he seems to want to remove that functionality completely as an alternative, but he doesnt make that clear.
I am not questioning it's usability, I am questioning why we cant make is less automatic, happen less often or only on demand, using the graphical frontend (and the answer could be to request a frontend improvement), and finally, how to solve the problem even if temporarily for now.
Now, on **how to solve it**, the answers are identical, here and there, but the questions are different.
In the past, I have argumented this extensive way, logically, explaining why my point of view is right, and it was completely ignored (there was no further talking) and even (mentally at least) downvoted by managers on stackexchange, so I expect nothing less now, now just waiting to see this final text block be removed, as usual :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I really need apt-daily.service and apt-daily-upgrade.service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038923/do-i-really-need-apt-daily-service-and-apt-daily-upgrade-service)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little brute force, but you could

```
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.service apt-daily-upgrade.service
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.timer apt-daily-upgrade.timer
```

Comment: this boot, aptd did not start. I dont know what was the `apt-daily.timer` config tho, was every boot? was 1 day? was 15 days? so I dont know if aptd will be triggered again by some other means than thru systemctl cfg, but for now it looks good. I wonder if will remain like that 1 month from now? :)

Comment: @AquariusPower I assume it will stay off, perhaps until something re-enables the services.

Comment: it may happen? mm... I will create a check everytime I run a new bash session (terminal) to see if it gets changed some day thx!

Comment: @AquariusPower I'm thinking maybe if there's some giant update, but I really don't think so.  I've had mine disabled approx 2 months...